# Type 'Client | undefined' is not assignable to type 'Client' using angular12 and firebase

Tags: angular, firebase

i created a client management application i allowed to display clients, and i have for each client a details button to display the details of a client, so i want to retrieve the details of a client but it me gives error: `Type 'Client | undefined 'is not assignable to type' Client '`.
visual code underlines it on `this.client = client;`

**client.services.ts**

```
getClient(id:string) {
     return this.clientsCollection.doc(id).valueChanges();
   }
```

**model Client**

```
export interface Client{
    id? : string,
    firstname? : string,
    lastname? : string,
    email? : string,
    phone? : number,
    balance : number
}
```

**details-client.component.ts**

```
ngOnInit(): void {
     this.id = this.router.snapshot.params['id'];
     this.clientService.getClient(this.id).subscribe(client => {
       this.client = client;
       console.log(this.client);
     });
  }
```

Comment: `getClient` possibly returns an `undefined` value, thus in the callback of `subscribe` the `client` may also be `undefined`, but `this.client` does not allow a value of `undefined`. Check the value of `client` is set, before you assign it to `this.client`

Comment: @derpirscher thx for you aswer,how can i verify that getClient retern customer details

Comment: this.client = client!; should work. this syntax tells ts that here we will always have a value

Comment: `this.client = client!` fixes the compilation issue. And if it's guaranteed that `client` will always be set, its ok to use a non-null assertion `!`. But if there is a possiblity, that `getClient()` indeed returns a `null` or `undefined` you should check with `if (client) this.client = client` and probably raise an error otherwise ...